# Coalesce array of integers in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

`foo_ids` is an array of type `bigint`, but the entire array could be null.  If the array is null, I want an empty array instead.

If I do this: `COALESCE(foo_ids, ARRAY())`

I get:

`FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10016]: Line 13:45 Argument type mismatch 'ARRAY': The expressions after COALESCE should all have the same type: "array<bigint>" is expected but "array<string>" is found`

If I do this: `COALESCE(foo_ids, ARRAY<BIGINT>())`

I get a syntax error: `FAILED: ParseException line 13:59 cannot recognize input near ')' ')' 'AS' in expression specification`

What's the proper syntax here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this one:

### coalesce(foo_ids, array(cast(null as bigint)))

Before, hive is treating empty array [] as []. But in Hadoop2, hive is now showing empty array [] as null (see refence below).  Use array(cast(null as bigint)) for empty array of type bigint. Strangely, the size of empty array is -1 (instead of 0).  Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
Sample data:
foo_ids 
[112345677899098765,1123456778990987633]        
[null,null]     
NULL    

select foo_ids, size(foo_ids) as sz from tbl;
Result:
foo_ids                                        sz
[112345677899098765,1123456778990987633]        2
[null,null]                                     2
NULL                                           -1

select foo_ids, coalesce(foo_ids, array(cast(null as bigint))) as newfoo from tbl;
Result:
foo_ids                                         newfoo
[112345677899098765,1123456778990987633]        [112345677899098765,1123456778990987633]
[null,null]                                     [null,null] 
NULL                                            NULL
```

Reference: https://docs.treasuredata.com/articles/hive-change-201602

Comment: My concern is not about null values in the array, but with the entire array being null.  So for your last test case I want to go from `NULL` -> `[]`.  Maybe this is not possible.

Comment: Correct.  [] is now NULL as per hadoop 2.